# Should I add results from one question to a similar, older question?

Tags: discussion

I provided [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/27699321/purpose-of-matrix-length/27700676#27700676) to a MATLAB question today. The comments made me do some more research and I found [this older question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3119739/difference-between-matlabs-numel-and-length-functions) from 2010, which is similar but not identical. I tried to verify the results from the old question and got different results, as the newer version of MATLAB seems to have improved in this field.

I summarized this in my answer to the new question. Now, should I add another answer to the old question, describing how this has changed in newer versions? Or is it better to leave the old question/answer as it is?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

It's always good to update old posts when the associated technology changes. That way visitors don't waste their time trying solutions that won't work for their current platform.

You have several options:

- Write your own answer, mention that the current accepted/upvoted answer no longer works for MATLAB version X.Y and up, and provide an alternate solution that does work.
- Write a comment on the current accepted/upvoted answer that it no longer works and should be updated for MATLAB version X.Y and up. *(You can do this in addition to writing your own answer, since your answer will probably appear at the bottom of the page; you still want people who only see the top answer to know that it is probably obsolete.)*
- Edit the current accepted/upvoted answer with a note that it no longer works and provide an alternate solution for MATLAB version X.Y and up. *(I would only take this route if the original author is unlikely to ever come back.)*